# Google Play - How to prevent downloading the large APK Expansion File when the user installs the APP from the market

Tags: android, download, google-play, apk, apk-expansion-files

many of my users have problems to install my App from the Play Store due to a lack of enought internal memory. The size of the App is: APK 37MB + EXPANSION 1,3 GB.

I was aware that many users don't want to have such big data in the system memory and implemented the licencing- and download-libary example, and changed the code that the expansion-file will be downloaded directliy to the physical sd-card. But the user can run my download-process only from the options-menu **within** the App.

.

**The problem**:

Google stated [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#DownloadProcess):

> "...If Google Play is unable to download the expansion files, it downloads the APK only."

But this seems to be wrong. Many user complain about installation issues and "pending/hanging" downloads. They say that when they install the App from the market that Google Play tries to download the  OBB-Expansion File in the first place and (what makes it even worse) to the **internal** memory.
So the user can not start the App and make use of my download implementation.

As I want to make use of the security features of google's licensing mechanisms I had following idea:

1. Upload my app to the developer console without the expansion.
2. Upload another dummy-apk with the 1,3GB expansion, and don't publish it
3. Try to download the Expansion from the options-menu from my original app und use the licence-key from the dummy apk.

Can somebody confirm that this could work?

Is there an way to make Google Play download the large expansion directly to the **external** memory? Maybe if i modify the Manifest with:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Any Ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the preferExternal value for installLocation in your manifest? This will put all files in external storage if available. Do this for all your apk files.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

from: [app install location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)